# Decode a ulaw encoded SPH file

Tags: speech-recognition, wav, sox, htk

**This problem is solved**

**My task**:
I have a .sph file with the following file-header:

> NIST_1A
>      1024
>   conversation_id -s4 2001
>   database_id -s25 Switchboard-1_release-2.0
>   channel_count -i 1
>   **sample_coding -s4 ulaw**
>   **channels_interleaved -s4 TRUE**
>   sample_count -i 2018387
>   sample_rate -i 8000
>   sample_n_bytes -i 1
>   sample_sig_bits -i 8
>   end_head

I want to transfer the above file to a .sph file without encoded and without the channels_interleaved behavior, so that I will have a file header look like this:

> NIST_1A
>      1024
>   conversation_id -s4 2001
>   database_id -s25 Switchboard-1_release-2.0
>   **channel_count -i 1**
>   sample_count -i 2018387
>   sample_rate -i 8000
>   **sample_coding -s4 pcm**
>   **sample_n_bytes -i 2**
>   **sample_sig_bits -i 16**
>   end_head

**My method**:
sph2pipe -c 1 -p input output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert sph file to wav format with sph2pipe use

```
sph2pipe -f rif file.sph file.wav
```

To convert file with SOX use

```
sox file.sph file.wav
```

although complex compression methods like shorten might not be supported. For your particular file it will work fine:

HTK can handle such files perfectly too, for details see the section *5.11.4 NIST File Format* in HTKBook. You need to configure SOURCEFORMAT=NIST in config file. For switchboard specifically you also need to split channels with STEREOMODE set to LEFT or RIGHT.